# Is there a way to extract list from list without making it a List<List<>> situation?

Tags: c#, linq

Extract list from list of lists...

I have a structure like

```
Struct1
{
 public int blah-blah
 public string blah-blah-blah
 public List<Struct2> problematicList
}

var problem = List<Struct1>
```

And I want to exctract all of Struct2's elements from a List of Struct1
Query like

```
List<Struct2> struct2s= 
                problem.Select(x => x.problematicList.Struct2).ToList();
```

gives me a list of lists, and I can't wrap my head around of how to do it corretly with a singular linq query. There must be a way, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0).

Using `SelectMany`, you would write something like the following:

```
List<Struct2> struct2s = problem.SelectMany(x => x.problematicList).ToList();
```